# Release resources and safely delete file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using code bellow to serialize data into myObject

```
 public static void SerializeObject(string filename, MyObject objectToSerialize)
 {
      Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
      BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      bformatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
     stream.Close();                
 }
```

This code works fine, but I'm having problem with deleting temporary files (here presented as parameter (filename)).

I'm assuming that problem is in this method code above, so how can I release any resource this code uses so I can delete file.

Comment: First, this is not defensive coding. Where's the `using` to ensure the `stream` is closed even if something fails etc.? Second, why are you passing data through a temporary file in the first place? Also, your description is wrong, you're actually serializing the object to a file, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have any problems deleting the file when I tried your program but I think you should be using the following:

```
public static void SerializeObject(string filename, MyObject objectToSerialize)
{
    var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    bformatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
    stream.Close();                
}
```

I am not sure that converting to a Stream a FileStream causes any issues, it probably does not anyway.

But this is even probably easier and more fool proof as it ensures that the stream gets closed properly:

```
    public static void SerializeObject(string filename, Object objectToSerialize)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bformatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
        }
    }
```

If you find a way to reproduce your issue, let me know: as I mentioned, I could delete the file after executing your function and while still running the program, so I cannot reproduce your issue.